# Getting the connections(friends)list from linked in using linkedin API in IPhone?

Tags: iphone

I have an application using linked in API.I downloaded the code from "http://github.com/ResultsDirect/LinkedIn-iPhone" and successfully implementad it for login.
But now i want to get all my contacts from my linked in account through this application .Can anybody tell me how to do it with this API.Any help will be greatly appreciated